# Code slow down as report grows

Tags: vba, excel

I have been running this code in my day to day work to keep on top of my orders and shipping, the code opens a spreadsheet in a specified location and returns the following, invoice number, company name, shipping date and total order value and puts them into one main spreadsheet.

I started using it last year and it used to take just under 3 minutes to run through about 400-500 spread sheets to collect the data. now I have a similar amount of data to run through this year but the report takes hours!!

I haven't changed my report and the data is the same data from the same template just in a different folder but in the same location on the same drive under the same parent folder.

I don't think it s the change of location that has slowed it down.

I have included a copy of my code below with notes under most of the code to explain the function of each line, can anyone see any problems with the code or recommend any improvements?

```
Sub Invoice_Records()
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim objFile As Object
    Dim FileExt As String
    Dim CellValue As Range
    Dim Text As String
    Dim Text2 As String
    Dim Text3 As String
    Dim Total As Range
    Dim filecountB As String
    Dim i As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim Invoice_Count As Integer

    Set ws = Worksheets("Admin2")

    'This part clears all columns, otherwise if you were on line 10 last time you ran the code,
    'and then you deleted a commercial invoice it would only update up to line 9 but the legacy values of line 10 would still show
    ws.Columns(2).EntireColumn.Clear
    ws.Columns(3).EntireColumn.Clear
    ws.Columns(4).EntireColumn.Clear
    ws.Columns(5).EntireColumn.Clear
    ws.Columns(6).EntireColumn.Clear
    ws.Columns(7).EntireColumn.Clear

    'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    'Get the folder object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\king_matthew\Documents\ELINV 2018")
    filecountB = objFolder.Files.Count
    i = 1
    'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
        'print file name
        ws.Cells(i + 1, 2) = objFile.Name
        'print file path
        ws.Cells(i + 1, 3).Select
        ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:=objFile.Path, TextToDisplay:=objFile.Path
        'Get the file extension
        FileExt = Right(objFile.Name, Len(objFile.Name) - InStrRev(objFile.Name, "."))
        'Paste file extension in column D
        ws.Cells(i + 1, 4) = FileExt
        If FileExt = "xlsm" Then
            'This line stops the excel documents opening on your screen they just open in the background meaning your screen does not flicker
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            Application.StatusBar = True
            Application.StatusBar = "Currently processing item " + i + " out of " + filecountB
            'This opens the documents

            Workbooks.Open Filename:=objFile.Path
            'Tells VBA what you are looking for
            Text = "Total Invoice Value"
            'Find text, defined in line above
            Set Match = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(Text)
            'Get the value of the cell next to cell found above
            findoffset = Match.Offset(, 1).Value
            'Paste this value in to column F
            ws.Cells(i + 1, 6) = findoffset
            'Tells VBA what else to look for
            Text2 = "Order No:"
            'Find Text2, defined in line above
            Set Index = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(Text2)
            'If "Order No:" cant be found then do below if it is found skip to ELSE
            If Index Is Nothing Then
                'Tells VBA what else to look for
                Text3 = "Date:"
                'Find text, defined in line above
                Set Match2 = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(Text3)
                'Get the value of the cell next to cell found above
                findoffset = Match2.Offset(, 1).Value
                'Close the workbook
                ActiveWorkbook.Close
                'Turn screen updating on so that you can see the values being updated
                Application.ScreenUpdating = True
                'Paste this value in to column F
                ws.Cells(i + 1, 5) = findoffset
                'Go onto the next file
                i = i + 1
            Else
                'Paste the "Order No:" in column G
                ws.Cells(i + 1, 7) = Index
                'Tells VBA what else to look for
                Text3 = "Date:"
                'Find text, defined in line above
                Set Match2 = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(Text3)
                'Get the value of the cell next to cell found above
                findoffset = Match2.Offset(, 1).Value
                'Close the workbook
                ActiveWorkbook.Close

                'Paste this value in to column F
                ws.Cells(i + 1, 5) = findoffset
                'Go onto the next file
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Else
            'If file extension is anything other than XLSM then leave the date blank
            ws.Cells(i + 1, 5) = ""
            'Go onto the next file
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next objFile
    'Turn screen updating on so that you can see the values being updated
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Application.StatusBar = False

    Call FindingLastRow

End Sub

Sub FindingLastRow()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set ws = Worksheets("Admin2")



    'Rows.count returns the last row of the worksheet (which in Excel 2007 is 1,048,576); Cells(Rows.count, "A")
    'returns the cell A1048576, ie. last cell in column A, and the code starts from this cell moving upwards;
    'the code is bascially executing Range("A1048576").End(xlUp), and Range("A1048576").End(xlUp).Row finally returns the last row number.
    lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row

    ws.Range("Row_Number").Value = lastRow

End Sub
```

Comment: what are you using the `FindingLastRow` sub for? It seems like it serves no purpose but to slow things down. That operation is simple enough that it should really just be done in the sub it is being used instead

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so I changed a few things and removed some unnecessary code. Here is my "changelog":

- Commented out call to `FindingLastRow` as it currently does nothing
- Moved the 'Dims' around so that they are easier to read
- Removed unused variables
- Added variables for the temporary workbooks

  - I did this to avoid using `ActiveSheet` which will slow code down
  - NOTE: The line that sets `wsTemp` might not work correctly, let me know if it fails
- Grouped the columns.clear calls you made
- Changed starting value of `i` to 2 for simplicity
- Added range variables to catch the `Range.Find("..")` results
- Moved `Application.ScreenUpdating` call outside of loop

  - No reason to have it toggle so frequently inside of the loop itself
- Added toggle to `.Calculation` and `.EnableEvents` to potentially speed program up further

  - They act similarly to `.ScreenUpdating` by suppressing excel and speed up by focusing on only certain operations
- Removed the `.select` for the hyperlinks

  - Like calling `Activesheet`, calling `.select` will also slow code down
- String concatenation for StatusBar uses `&` instead of `+`
- Changed around how the `if` statements were used to clear out duplicate code

  - A couple times you were repeating code in the `if`s when you can just do it right *after* them
- Re-ordered the value pasting to match the columns theyre pasted in (ie C,D,E,F,G )
- When calling cells using `.cells(r,c)` you can actually just use the column string, so I did that for simplicity

  - NOTE: your comments said that 'Date' would go in column F but your actual code put it in column E, so I chose to use E
- Started using `.value2` and `.value` when accessing/pasting text into cells

  - NOTE: added offset to the "order no" to match your other searches (it looked like an oversight)
- I think that's it???

---

With all that in mind, here is the result. Hopefully it scales properly with your folder now :)

```
Sub Invoice_Records()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Admin2")

    Dim wbTemp As Workbook
    Dim wsTemp As Worksheet

    'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
    Dim objFSO As Object
    Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

    'Get the folder object
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("C:\Users\king_matthew\Documents\ELINV 2018")

    Dim objFile As Object

    Dim i As Long
    i = 2

    Dim FileExtension As String

    Dim filecountB As String
    filecountB = objFolder.Files.count

    Dim searchInvValue As Range
    Dim searchOrderNum As Range
    Dim searchDate As Range

    'Toggling screen updating prevents screen flicker and speeds up operations
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .EnableEvents = False
        .StatusBar = True
    End With

    'This part clears all columns, otherwise if you were on line 10 last time you ran the code,
    'and then you deleted a commercial invoice it would only update up to line 9 but the legacy values of line 10 would still show
    ws.Columns("B:G").EntireColumn.Clear

    'Loops through each file in the directory
    For Each objFile In objFolder.Files

        'Update status bar to show progress
        Application.StatusBar = "Currently processing item " & (i - 1) & " out of " & filecountB

        'Paste file name
        ws.Cells(i, "B").Value2 = objFile.Name

        'Paste file path and add a hyperlink to it
        ws.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=ws.Cells(i, "C"), Address:=objFile.path, TextToDisplay:=objFile.path

        'Get the file extension
        FileExtension = UCase$(Right(objFile.Name, Len(objFile.Name) - InStrRev(objFile.Name, ".")))

        'Paste file extension
        ws.Cells(i, "D").Value2 = FileExtension

        'Only do operations on files with the extension "xlsm", otherwise skip
        If FileExtension = "xlsm" Then

            'This opens the current "objFile" document
            Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=objFile.path)
            Set wsTemp = wbTemp.Sheets(1)

            'Find and paste "Date:"
            Set searchDate = wsTemp.Cells.Find("Date:")
            ws.Cells(i, "E").value = searchDate.Offset(, 1).value

            'Find and paste "Total Invoice Value"
            Set searchInvValue = wsTemp.Cells.Find("Total Invoice Value")
            ws.Cells(i, "F").Value2 = searchInvValue.Offset(, 1).Value2

            'Find "Order No:" and paste if not blank
            Set searchOrderNum = wsTemp.Cells.Find("Order No:")
            If Not searchOrderNum Is Nothing Then ws.Cells(i, "G").Value2 = searchOrderNum.Offset(, 1).Value2

            'Close the current "objFile" workbook
            wbTemp.Close
        End If

        'Go onto the next file
        i = i + 1
    Next objFile

    'Turn screen updating back on so that you can see the values being updated
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        .EnableEvents = True
        .StatusBar = False
    End With

    'Call FindingLastRow        'this does not currently seem necessary

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Marcucciboy2, thank you for the help I have rewritten the code with your changes and it has definitely made my code easier to understand and now makes more sense to me about what each section is doing, I have run the code and it does work but it hasn't sped up at all it is still painfully slow. could it be a problem with the files i'm getting the data from? The files i'm getting the information from are basically the same as last year but as time has gone on I have added formulas and snippets of code to automate things.

Comment: @mattking the operations that are really slowing you down are using `wsTemp.Cells.Find(...)` three times for every sheet. One way you could speed it up greatly is to drop the `.Find` if the location of those fields is consistent. If it's not, though, then what you can do is specify a smaller range that they could be in so it does not have to search so much. Right now we say `ws.Cells` but we could actually do like `ws.Range("A1:Z1")` and it would certainly help

Comment: I can change that part of the code thank you for the tip, but I still cant work out why the code now takes hours not minutes when you saw the state of the code I was using last year and it was still running in under 5 minutes! I don't use the report anymore because of how long it takes but I used to use it daily as a way of keeping on top of my workload so I could easily see what had been done etc. Also I have played around with the code but for some reason it is not returning any information for the order number column, any ideas?

Comment: @mattking that change I gave was an example and should probably be a smaller range than I listed there. Can you answer to whether every sheet has this information in (at least generally) the same place? I'm trying to understand what changed with the data in a year that might have caused the slow down. Did it grow in each sheet you have to search? did the number of sheets grow? Third, is the order number itself adjacent and to the right of the "order number" cell?

Comment: The data is almost exactly the same as last year, the template has stayed relatively the same. and the order number is in a merged cell so it is in the same cell as "Order Number". Do you have an email address I could send you a copy of the commercial invoices 1 from last year one from this year to see what information the report is gathering.

Comment: @mattking sure, it's just my username at gmail